# Redefine a python function based on another class function based on type

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm more of an engineer and less of a coder, but I know enough python and C++ to be dangerous.

I'm creating a python vector/matrix class as a helper class based upon numpy as well as cvxopt.  The overall goal (which I've already obtained... the answer to this question will just make the class better) is to make dot products and other processes more unified and easier for numerical methods.

However, I'd like to make my helper class even more transparent.  What I'd like to do is to redefine the cvxopt.matrix() init function based upon the current variable which was used.  This is to say, if I have a custom matrix: "cstmat", I'd like the function "cvxopt.matrix(cstmat)" to be defined by my own methods instead of what is written in the cvxopt class.

In short, I'd like to "intercept" the other function call and use my own function.

The kicker, though, is that I don't want to take over cvxopt.matrix(**any_*other*_type**).  I just want to redefine the function when it's called upon my own custom class.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: I think that the standard approach is to subclass the object, and have the child class function check for the type, and if it is not the one you want to process yourself, hand it down to the paren't function.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but I do not want to fumble with the parent class (it's written in c and wrapped with python).  Would I need to redefine the __init__ call on the parent class?

Comment: You are already trying to fumble with the class, and also implicitly (people who read the client code wouldn't easily know which version of class it's using). Remember: explicit is better that implicit, and beautiful is better than ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's not pretty.

You can do probably something along these lines:

```
cvxopt._orig_matrix = cvxopt.matrix

def my_matrix(*args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(arg[0], cstmat):
        # do your stuff here
    else:
        cvxopt._orig_matrix(*args, **kwargs)

cvxopt.matrix = my_matrix
```

But you're probably better off finding a less weird way.  And no guarantees that won't forget who "self" is.

Better would be to use inheritance!  Kinda like this:

```
class Cstmat(cvsopt.matrix):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        pass

    def matrix(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, cstmat):
            # do your stuff here
        else:
            cvsopt.matrix(arg)
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm already doing something like this, but what I want to do is to intercept the other function's init class instead.  How would inheritance help me here: I'm making a helper class composed of two classes (please excuse my ignorance)?  The called __init__ function on the previously written class has no knowledge of my new class?

Comment: Moreover, could I write the custom class to include inheritance of both numpy and cvxopt type matrices?